# How to Facet Search on Solr?

Tags: solr, e-commerce, solrnet, faceted-search

I am new to Solr and I don't know how to fire a query for Facet search.
I have the following fields in my schema (I have put a schema.XML here).
I have total 6 fields, on which I can try faceting. Is there any field to define for Faceting in schema.xml file?

```
<fields>
<field name="P_ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="P_NAME" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
<field name="P_SKU" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" /> 
<field name="P_METADESCRIPTION" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" 
required="false" /> 
<field name="P_PRICE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" /> 
<field name="P_OLDPRICE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" /> 
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>   
  </fields>
  <unique Key>P_ID</unique Key> 
  <defaultSearchField>P_NAME</defaultSearchField>
```

How could I make a facet search query here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, for faceting you don't have to modify anything in schema.xml. For better understanding about Facet search please go through the following link.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters

Comment: Just found your post and FYI to all that the page is 404